# flowchart of "cp" command in linux

Tags: linux

I want to know how does `cp` command get executed. I mean its flow from top most layer to kernel and back again? What is its flow? What happens when we write `cp` command and how it happens? please tell it in detail.

Comment: Its rude to say i want an answer ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

`foo.c` **contents before cp:**

```
this is foo
```

`strace cp foo.c bar.c` **gave me this:**

```
execve("/bin/cp", ["cp", "foo.c", "bar.c"], [/* 58 vars */]) = 0

//several calls to open, fstat64, mmap2, close

open("foo.c", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)     = 3
    fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=12, ...}) = 0

    open("bar.c", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0664) = 4
        fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
        read(3, "this is foo\n", 32768)         = 12
        write(4, "this is foo\n", 12)           = 12
        read(3, "", 32768)                      = 0
    close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0

close(0)                                = 0  // close stdin
close(1)                                = 0  // close stdout
close(2)                                = 0  // close stderr
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do a [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) on a cp command like:

```
$ strace cp foo bar
```

This way you'll see all the `system calls` made by the `cp` command.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably download the sources. If you have some debian:

```
#this will tell you what package cp comes from
dpkg -S "$(which cp)"
apt-get source the_package_name_here
```